# ¿Cómo poner borde a un cardView con androiX?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

**Compañeros**, me es imposible poner un simple borde a un cardview! Espero puedan ayudarme!

**Contexto:** Utilizo: androidx.cardview.widget.CardView y tengo declaradas estas dependencias en el build.gradle: 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' y 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0', que entiendo son esenciales para el cardView. ¿Para qué quiero los cardViews? Esencialmente tengo un recyclerView que muestra los cardViews en cuestión.

Va el XML de mi layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#FFEB3B"
        app:cardCornerRadius="70dp"
        app:cardElevation="1dp"
        app:contentPadding="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/textViewTerminado"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TableRow>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:text="@string/nombre"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewNombre"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingRight="10sp"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:text="@string/autor"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewAutor"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingRight="10sp"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </TableRow>

            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Y aquí una imagen de cómo se ve en mi teléfono:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Preguntas:**

1. ¿Por qué el perímetro del cardCornerRadius (que forma extremos
   puntiagudos al cardView) no coincide con el borde impreso por el
   cardElevation (o sea el borde gris)? ¿No deberían coincidir?
2. Y la pregunta más importante, ¿cómo puedo lograr que el borde impreso por el cardElevation (o sea el borde gris) se vea en los 4 lados del cardView? Ya que actualmente no se muestra en la parte inferior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba el siguiente approach, es una vista más eficiente ya que está formado por un CardView + ConstraintLayout, en tu caso tienes un Relative+CardView+Linear+TabLayout...

En este caso se está empleando MaterialCardView, puedes usar de la librería androidx el CardView.

Y cuidado con las CardView, si quieres elevation también se le puede poner a otra ViewGroup como Constraint y, si necesitas el bordes redondeados, puedes crear un shape en xml... por lo que no le veo ventajas a este approach, de todas formas te dejo el código del layout.xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:elevation="1dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background_item_author"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_iv"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/name_title_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/author_title_tv"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/image_iv"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/image_iv"
            tools:text="Nombre" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/author_title_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/image_iv"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/image_iv"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/name_title_tv"
            tools:text="Autor" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/name_description_tv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/name_title_tv"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/name_title_tv"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/name_title_tv"
            tools:text="EL nombre que sea" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/author_description_tv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/author_title_tv"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/name_title_tv"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/author_title_tv"
            tools:text="EL autor que sea" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

El background_item_author.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid
        android:color="#ffeb3b"/>

    <corners android:radius="56dp" />

    <size
        android:width="120dp"
        android:height="120dp"/>
</shape>
```

Si necesitas poner en este shape un borde, tienes el atributo stroke.

El resultado en el visor de Android, al ejecutarlo lo verás bien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si vas a traducir la app, mírate los Barriers, ya que Nombre y Autor en otros idiomas pueden ocupar mucho espacio en pantalla, y así te ayudará a poner límtes.

También fíjate que si es sólo español y no va a cambiar, el wrap content de name y author title está bien, pues cuando la vista se recicle, el tamaño es fijo.  Y en el caso del nombre y autor description, ocupan toda la pantalla  (width 0dp con constraintStart y End), además de maxLine 1, de esta forma todas las vistas tendrán el mismo estilo y es mejor para reciclar la vista.

Prueba a borrar el contenedor MaterialButton y dale elevation al contenedor ConstraintLayout, igual es lo que necesitas.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, en verdad me sirvió mucho. Simplemente dejé todo como estaba y cree el background_item_author.xml que sugeriste, el cual lo asigné como background al RelativeLayout que ya tenía, y pum, funcionó. Al parecer, debo entender que si quiero meter diseño custom a un view, tengo siempre que crear XML para eso, ¿correcto? Gracias nuevamente!

Comment: Siempre que quieras hacer un item list con diseño personalizado sí, tienes que recurrir al xml... así que por lo general siempre crearás tus vistas.

Comment: ah y se me olvidaba... mi código no está bien, hay que usar match parent o 0dp en los textview, porque la recycler querrá reciclar el viewholder... de esta manera se evita que vuelva a calcular el espacio para el texto.